# Objects missing from final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

So I am fairly new to blender. I wanted to create a night scene with a small bridge. But when I try to render the scene some objects are missing in the final render. They all show up in the rendered view and in the viewport. I tried troubleshooting it but everything appears normal.
Link to my .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CSaxXX_rJv0MlFAQg2YPpL4nA-FsSDs5/view?usp=sharing
Thanks for your help in advance.[image: PreviewRender] [image: Final render]

Comment: could you probide your .blend file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/P9A71XNd here you go

Comment: You have many collections, open the full hierarchy on the outliner (numpad +) and look for objects that might be disabled for rendering (camera icon)

Comment: I did that and everything is enabled for rendering :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you used the BlenderKit Asset Library addon to get models in your scene. It seems to work with Instancing of collections. I think for the Import Method of the asset library you chose Link. (personally I would have used Append)

If i open your file there is only geometry data for 3 objects (the ground, the background and the mountains). The other geometry is not in your file but somewhere else, and it is linked to your file.

Possibly the file paths of the missing objects are not correct (maybe the files where moved), and your blender file can't find the needed files/objects/geometry.

One way to solve this is to Append your objects in the future. This way they become part of you blender file, and are not dependent on correct links/file paths.

(Be aware though, the problem might be something different all together, but since i don't have the files that are linked to your blender file, it is hard for me to tell.)

Comment: Scroll down on the BlederKit panel and you'll find two buttons under Import Method. One says Link and the other one says Append. And please keep me updated about if it will make any difference. I'd be happy to take another look if it doesn't.

Comment: I changed the method to append now and tried to import the same asset. And it still does not appear in the render :(

Comment: I was afraid of that : ) Can you upload a file of that? Then i can have another look, but this time with object(s) (that don't render) in the 3D Viewport for me to see.

Comment: I kind of figured it our now. I appended the objects from the .blend files from the directory they are downloaded to. And now they render if I put them in the scene. So your answer definetly got me on the right track thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help : )